# Improve loose thread fitting

Tags: bolts, joints, fitting

I have 10 laser pens of the same type(cheap Chinese ones) in aluminum and the threads are a bit loose, is there any way to improve the friction for the threads by applying some friction grease/paste? its for adjusting the focus of the lens so right now there is a slight wiggling room that i would like to get rid of.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about home improvement per network guidelines.

Comment: Oh I thought this was a general diy, which stackexchange is my question more suitable for my question then?

Comment: Yeah, the URL is "DIY....", but the focus is Home Improvement. I don't know of a better place for this question, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try Teflon plumbers tape. It will maintain the shape of the threads as it increases the diameter of the male threads, and will still let you disassemble the unit at need.

Comment: This is can be a bit tricky because it has a locking mechanism which prevents it from totally unscrewing.